# What is weakly-labeled data?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am afraid I ask an easy question, but here are my questions:

What is weakly-labeled data and is there any strongly-labeled data? In what situation do we use them?

Comment: No one can help?

Answer (score 5):

Weakly-labeled data is data that has not *explicitly* been labeled by hand / manually. However, it is not *unlabeled*, because you know that certain assumptions do hold for an entire data set.

To give an example, let's say you want to design some recognition software that works with images of humans.

A **labeled** (infrequently also called *fully*-labeled or *strongly*-labeled) data set would not only contain the images of specific humans, but would also contain labels that were created manually, like *gender*, *hair color*, *occupation*, *body height*, *weight*, ...

A **weakly-labeled** data set would only contain unlabeled sets of images including meta information that holds for every image inside a set. For example, if you do not label the images, but record only *male* people, only *firemen*, ... then you basically have "unlabeled" data but you know at least *some* meta-information that you can use to categorize your data. Thus, the knowledge of this data is less strong / informative compared to labeled data, but it is not *zero*.

An **unlabeled** data set in comparison really contains *zero* information that could be used to distinguish single samples of the data set. For our example of humans this would be recording people of any *gender*, *hair color*, *occupation*, ..., resulting in one big data set without meta information about the single samples.